# Can the Line-in jack be used for an external microphone?

Tags: microphone, line-level

Is there any way to use a microphone in a Line-in jack (e.g., with a pre-amp, phantom power, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an external [microphone preamplifier](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/mic-preamp-buying-guide/), these convert the mic signal to line level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  And your question included the answer how!   The item that changes a mic level signal to line level is called a preamp.  And if the mic is a type that requires phantom power, a preamp can provide it.

Don't get sucked into the world of boutique preamps.  It's an easy job that can be done cheaply.

You might consider something like this.  It's a bit more than just a simple microphone preamp, but its facilities could come in useful for  other things.

https://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_xenyx_502.htm